# How to use jquery in npm compiled js file without compiling jquery into the output

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack

Unfortunately I am getting conflicts with a wordpress plugin loading jQuery into the `<head>`, and then I have jQuery compiled into my npm `main.js` file which loads in the footer.

This is how I am loading jQuery into my npm `main.js` file...

```
// load jquery
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
```

If I remove this line, my conflict issue is resolved but I then get this errors...

[image]

This is my tooltip function which works fine when jquery is compiled into the file.

```
// tool tip config
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    boundary: 'scrollParent',
    placement: 'top'
});
```

So all my jQuery that is called in `main.js` stops working.

```
// commons functions
(function ($) {

    // nothing jquery works in here

})(jQuery);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in npm main.js file without compiling jQuery in to the mix? So I can jQuery separately in the head.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an import instead. Require is not the appropriate method for that -

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```